# What a mean of iterable object in python 3 in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

** to run this program which add element into list **
**error  int object is not iterable**

> `d={'a':[1,4]}`
>
> `d['a']. extend (34)`

Comment: You have confused `extend` with `append`.

Comment: `extend` is expecting an object that can be iterated (e.g. `for x in [1, 4]`). You cannot loop through an `int` object.

Answer (score 1):

`d['a']` is a list. To add a single element to that list, either use `append()` or call `extend()` with an iterable (such as a list or a tuple):

```
d['a'].append(34)
d['a'].extend([34])
```

For further background, see [What exactly are iterator, iterable, and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)

Comment: @user9405787, This has nothing to do with dictionaries. `append` and `extend` are `list` methods.